# Geopandas buffer and intersect

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas

I am using the geojson file from the [OpenData Vancouver][1] website and I am trying to find the zoning classifications that fall within 5 kms of a "Historical Area".

So, I am buffering all historical areas by 5kms (My data is projected), performing the intersect operation and using the intersect results as an index:

```
buffs = gdf_26910[gdf_26910['zoning_classification']=='Historical Area']['geometry'].buffer(5000) 
gdf_26910[buffs.intersects(gdf_26910['geometry'])]
```

However, this is the output I am getting:

```
    zoning_category     zoning_classification   zoning_district     object_id   geometry    area    centroid    buffer5K
87  HA  Historical Area     HA-1A   78541   POLYGON ((492805.516 5458679.305, 492805.038 5...   3848.384041     POINT (492778.785 5458699.947)  POLYGON ((497803.807 5458548.605, 497803.124 5...
111     HA  Historical Area     HA-3    78640   POLYGON ((491358.402 5458065.050, 491309.735 5...   66336.339719    POINT (491183.139 5458103.162)  POLYGON ((492818.045 5453267.595, 492421.697 5...
180     HA  Historical Area     HA-1A   78836   POLYGON ((492925.194 5458575.204, 492929.600 5...   90566.768532    POINT (492753.969 5458456.804)  POLYGON ((487583.872 5458086.263, 487564.746 5...
683     HA  Historical Area     HA-1    78779   POLYGON ((492925.194 5458575.204, 492802.702 5...   69052.427940    POINT (492606.372 5458621.753)  POLYGON ((487874.100 5456398.633, 487789.801 5...
1208    HA  Historical Area     HA-2    78833   POLYGON ((492332.139 5458699.308, 492346.989 5...   179805.027166   POINT (492343.437 5458944.412)  POLYGON ((489822.136 5454379.453, 489755.087 5...
```

Clearly, I am getting a match for the Historical Areas and not all the other geometries that intersect the buffers.

I have plotted the buffers and the output looks correct:

```
#Plot
base=gdf_26910.plot()
buffs.plot(ax=base, color='red', alpha=0.25)
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I have also opened the data in QGIS and verified that there are 5 'Historical Areas' and they are all adjacent to 'Comprehensive Development'. So, the matching rows after the intersect operation should be "Comprehensive Development" at the least.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two core points

- need to work in meters for a 5km buffer.  Hence have used `estimate_utm_crs()` for projection.  Have also use `cap_style` and `join_style` for a more reflective buffered polygon.
- have used `sjoin()` instead of mask approach in your code.  This will effectively give duplicates,  so de-dupe using **pandas** `groupby().first()`
- **UPDATE** changed to `predicate="within"` and used **folium** to visualise (possibly helps you understand how geometry is working)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium

gdf_26910 = gpd.read_file(
    "https://opendata.vancouver.ca/explore/dataset/zoning-districts-and-labels/download/?format=geojson&timezone=Europe/London&lang=en"
)
buffs = gdf_26910.loc[gdf_26910["zoning_classification"] == "Historical Area"]
# buffer is defined as km, so need a CRS in meters...
buffs = (
    buffs.to_crs(buffs.estimate_utm_crs())
    .buffer(5000, cap_style=2, join_style=3)
    .to_crs(gdf_ha.crs)
)

# this warns so is clearly bad !
# gdf_26910[buffs.intersects(gdf_26910['geometry'])]
# some geometries intersect multiple historical areas,  take first intersection from sjoin()
gdf_5km = (
    gdf_26910.reset_index()
    .sjoin(buffs.to_frame(), predicate="within")
    .groupby("index")
    .first()
    .set_crs(gdf_26910.crs)
)

m = buffs.explore(name="buffer")
gdf_5km.explore("zoning_classification", m=m, name="within")
gdf_26910.explore("zoning_classification", m=m, name="all", legend=False)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

Comment: My data is already projected. So, just passing 5000 should be sufficient. I think when you are downloading the data, I think you are getting the unprojected data in EPSG:4236. That is why your plot has lat/long instead of coordinates in meters

Comment: ok - so it's the use of `sjoin()` that solves.  I was just following what you described for source of data

Comment: Still not getting the desired output. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: what output are you looking for?

Comment: updated to use **folium** visualisation which is interactive and possibly helps you understand the geometry

Comment: I had to change my code to account for the fact that the data is already projected. But using 'inner' sjoins using 'intersect' as the predicate worked,